# Why would a site ever use </img> in HTML markup

Tags: html, markup, image

I encountered this page https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin, a Google service login page that (beyond just omitting a doctype), contains 6 instances of `</img>`

For example,

```
  <img src="https://www.google.com/accounts/google_transparent.gif"
           alt="Google">
  </img>
```

Why would they ever do that? What benefit/functionality/grandfathering do they possibly achieve?

Anything I've ever read about HTML and XHTML has made it pretty unequovical:

In HTML 4.01 and prior, `<img>` tags are [never to be closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags) ( `<img src="img.gif" alt="text" >`).

In XHTML, `<img>` tags are to be closed using self-closing syntax ( `<img src='img.gif' alt="text" />`)

In HTML5, (my understanding is that) either syntax (open or self-closed) is acceptable, but still never `</img>`.

Comment: For consistency, mostly. IMO HTML5 got it right, since that is the way all other tags are done in HTML.  Why should `<img>` get special treatment?

Comment: I see your point. Then again writing something like `<br></br>` still feels wrong.

Comment: If XHTML is to be considered true XML, it can't declare you must use self-closing synxtax.  It must be acceptable to use self-closing (`<img/>`) or explicitly closed (`</img>`) tags. Its too bad Google didn't decalre a doctype.

Comment: @Bert F you're sort of right; XHTML 1.0/1.1 explicitly say that's bad practice to do so due to user agent behaviors. XHTML 2 tried to take the leap into XML purity by implementing </img> to match </object>, before is deep-sixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the only (proposed) way this code is ever actually compliant, though it does not apply in Google's case (since they lack a DOCTYPE).

XHTML 2, which was proposed and then scrapped, [implements a `</img>` tag as a way to replace the alt attribute.](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-image.html#edef_image_img)

So, instead of this in XHTML 1.0/1.1:

`<img src="monkeys.gif" alt="Monkeys throwing feces" />`

You'd have this

`<img src="monkeys.gif">Monkeys throwing feces</img>`

Where 'Monkeys throwing feces' only displays if monkeys.gif fails to load.

This would make `<img>` behave as other content embedding tags, like `<object>`.

In the spec's words,

> The img element is a holder for
>   embedding attributes such as src.
>   Since these attributes may be applied
>   to any element, the img element is not
>   strictly necessary, but is included to
>   ease the transition to XHTML2. Like
>   the object element, this element's
>   content is only presented if the
>   referenced resource is unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is a bug. In at least one case it seems to be just producing totally invalid code:

```
  <img class=logo
       src='https://www.google.com/intl/en/images/logos/accounts_logo.gif'
       alt="Google" />
  </img>
```

You can see the img tag is self closing and being closed by a separate closing tag. Clearly unintended. And its inconsistent which is a little weird too. I'd suggest e-mailing them and asking. :)

Comment: Nah, there's a ton of anecdotal evidence floating around the interwebs that the Google engineers just don't care about writing standard compliant code. Funny, since they're now one of the major browser vendors...

Comment: Maybe. I've certainly heard mention of them doign it to shorten pages but I can't see any reason to leave these things in and make the pages longer...Ah well, mine is not to question our great overlords at google... :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe their HTML-generator closes every `<tag>` with a corresponding `</tag>`, which is just a programmatically lazier alternative to writing `<tag/>` for such single tags.

Comment: Interesting thought, though that doesn't seem to be the close for the `<br>` tags (ie, no instances of `</br>`)