# Unwanted margin in inline-block list items

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
    <ul>
        <li>
        <div>first</div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div>first</div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div>first</div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div>first</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and the following css rules:

```css
        ul {
            padding: 0;
            border: solid 1px #000;
        }
        li {
            display:inline-block;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 114px;
            border: solid 1px #f00;
            margin: 0;
        }

        li div {
            background-color: #000;
            width: 114px;
            height: 114px;
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
```

For some strange reason, the list items appear with a margin around them in both Firefox and Chrome. Looking at firebug, the list items do not have any margin at all, but there seems to be a void space between them.

If I later on add more list items via javascript using

```
$('<li><div>added via js</div></li>').appendTo($('ul'));
```

the "margin" doesn't appear around the new elements:

[image: Unwanted margins]

Any idea of what the hell's happening here?

Comment: Why not use `margin-right: -4px;` Is there a reason why that shouldn't work?

Comment: Negative right margin depends on font-size and font used.

Comment: Seems like a lot of similar question get closed as the duplicate of this one, so a useful Chris Coyier link for future visitors: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This is caused by the `display: inline-block;`

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 114px;
    border: solid 1px #f00;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Change it to `float: left;`.

I thought it was the padding but took a closer look and turns out it was the display :)

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/4Mc7X/).

---

After [further research](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/) I have discovered that `inline-block` is a whitespace dependent method and renders a 4px margin to the right of each element.

To avoid this you could run all your `li`s together in one line, or block the end tags and begin tags together like this:

```
<ul>
        <li>
            <div>first</div>
        </li><li>
            <div>first</div>
        </li><li>
            <div>first</div>
        </li><li>
            <div>first</div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/t7dut/).

Comment: So it's a bug pertaining inline-block then, or is that the intended behaviour? In my opinion it doesn't make sense at all...

Comment: I think you're right. I honestly don't know why it would be adding new margins, then not on the new ones. It makes no sense. This is a fix but I'm still trying to figure out the reasons behind the "bug."

Comment: Found out the bug and made a fix for you :)

Comment: It's intended behaviour. `inline-block` was meant to emulate the behaviour of the `img` tag. Whitespace around an `inline-block` element will be rendered.

Comment: float: left fixed it for me, thanks

Comment: This is much better http://jsfiddle.net/t7dut/647/. Maybe rendering engines have changed since.

Comment: Ohh, man I wish I could give 50 upvotes for this. It gave answer to most of the questions. I always wondered why Twitter Bootstrap uses combination of `display:table` and `float:left` for column layout. This is the answer for that too.

Comment: The article mentions that it is a margin but what is happening is the inline element is rendering the word-space and line-height of the element by default.  Setting word-spacing: 0, and line-height: 0 on the parent container actually fixes this if you dont want to use float: left.

Comment: Is possible to do this with dynamic content?

Comment: this helped me understand my similar problem, but my answer that worked best for me was `li { display:table-cell; }`

Answer (score 68):

I found a very good trick to overcoming this very same issue. My list items in  my top menu had whitespace margins between each after i dropped "float:left;" in favor of "display:inline-block;".

Try setting your font-size for the unordered list to "0", ie:

```css
ul { font-size:0; }
li { font-size:18px; }
```

Worked for me.

Comment: To support Opera, add line-height: 0px to the ul.  To support Safari, you must set the font-size to 1px, not 0. (tested in Opera 12.01, Safari 5.1.7)

Comment: Don't use this method if you are depending on `em`s.

Comment: Can't believe this works, but it does. NICE.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: this is so genius, it works!!!!!!!

Comment: I know this is a super old answer, but I was tearing my hair out with an Angular ng-repeat where only the first li element had a margin. This answer solved the problem perfectly.

Comment: It worked for me, but not for vertical ul list. in my case setting the `ul{ font-size:0}` and `ul li>div{ font-size: 14px}` does the trick. Very nice trick though

Answer (score 9):

Seeing this post and the answers given, I thought I would explain what's going on here.  This is not a bug, but is actually the intended behavior of inline-block.

The best way to illustrate why this is the correct behavior is with smileys in a paragraph:

```
<p>
  Hi, really glad to hear from you yesterday 
  <img src="annoying_smiley.gif"/><img src="annoying_smiley.gif"/>.
</p>
```

Images are, by default, displayed as inline-block (IE: a block element which obeys the inline flow - much like a single character of text). In this case you would want the two smileys to butt up next to each other, but you would still want a space between 'yesterday' and the first smiley.

Hope this explains it, and also explains why inline-block has taken so long to be fully supported; There aren't actually many use-cases for using it as intended.

To answer your question, your best bet would be to do this:

```css
ul {
  height: some set height
       /* OR */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion and in this case the best thing to do is to remove the letter spacing of the `li`'s parent and re-put it on the `li`!

So your CSS rule:

```css
ul{
    padding: 0;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    letter-spacing  :-4px; /*Remove the letter spacing*/
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 114px;
    border: solid 1px #f00;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing  :0px; /*Put back the letter spacing*/ 

}
```

Comment: Ridiculous how well this works. Got an idea on its cross browser compatibility?

Answer (score 5):

Remove  all `</li>` tags.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>first</div>
    <li>
        <div>first</div>
    <li>
        <div>first</div>
    <li>
        <div>first</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: ? you mean avoiding ul at all or just taking out the closing tags?? why you should break the markup?

Comment: @Damien Pirsy: `</li>` tag is optional, it's safe to omit it. Here's more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags

Comment: That "fixes" the problem because it removes the unwanted whitespace between the end of first `<li>` element and start of the second `<li>` element. The same result can be achieved by *not* using any indention in the source code, which I consider much better style.

Answer (score 4):

I just found out the reason why this happens. It appears that when using inline-block, any whitespace inside the element is rendered.

So instead of writing

```
    <li>
    <div>first</div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div>first</div>
    </li>
```

I should write:

```
        <li>
            <div>first</div>
        </li><li><div>first</div>
        </li><li>....
```

Leaving no spaces between a li and it's closing tag. The reason why this space wasn't appearing when appending via js is because the appendTo method has all the tags without any whitespace between them.
Yeah, this sucks but it's the only solution if I don't want to use float:left.

Solution found [here](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

Comment: Indeed, when you have two inline elements (e.g. img) that you want next to each other, you can't leave any spaces in between. Same goes for elements that you want to be inline blocks.

Answer (score 4):

Changing `display: inline-block` to `display: table-cell` also removes the space.

```
    li {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 114px;
        border: solid 1px #f00;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to this question here: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

He says:

> "...there’s one giant drawback [to inline-block]. That is, since the elements become rendered inline, white-space in your HTML code will affect the rendering. That means, if we have space between the LI elements in our code, it will render a 4 pixel margin to the right of each element."

So the solution is to remove the line breaks between `inline-block` elements.

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Make</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Love</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Not</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">War</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Becomes...

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Make</a>
    </li><li>
      <a href="#">Love</a>
    </li><li>
      <a href="#">Not</a>
    </li><li>
      <a href="#">War</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the pesky margins disappear.

Comment: Best answer, needs up ! ;)

Comment: its not valid with documentation list ul li. In unordered list cant aby any element as a child. So in "ul" can be only "li" and then some element inside "li"

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
    <ul><!--
        --><li><div>first</div></li><!--
        --><li><div>first</div></li><!--
        --><li><div>first</div></li><!--
        --><li><div>first</div></li><!--
    --></ul>
```

Comment: Try providing an explanation with the code

Comment: It's a cheeky hack to remove the white space whilst retaining readability. The white space is what is causing the margin issue, adding comments such as this effectively removes the white space.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your 'display: inline-block' to 'float: left'. The separation that you are seeing then disappears. Here is a jsFiddle for you to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/XD9SD/

Bob

Comment: Here is an update with the javascript added. http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/XD9SD/1/