# Font sizing with em - what if base-size = 0?

Tags: html, css, font-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unwanted margin in inline-block list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969082/unwanted-margin-in-inline-block-list-items)
>   [A Space between Inline-Block List Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256533/a-space-between-inline-block-list-items)

To avoid the gap between to `li` set to `display: inline-block`, I've set the font size of the `ul` to 0. Hence the nature of em sizing, 0 is now passed as the base font-size for all `li`, which practically means that one can't see them.

Is there any way to solve this problem without setting `font-size: 14px` (for example) to the list items?

Comment: Just don’t set font size to 0. Whatever the original problem is, setting font size to 0 is a wrong solution.

Comment: why not just `float:left`? and avoid setting the `ul` `font-size: 0`, or if you must use `display: inline;` use `margin-right: -4px;`

Comment: This seems to have been covered a bunch.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5256640/1770042

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just float them instead Maybe they don't need to be inline-block at
>   all, maybe they can just be floated one way or another. That allows
>   you to set their width and height and padding and stuff. You just
>   can't center them like you can by text-align: center; the parent of
>   inline-block elements.

Take a look at this source: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

it list multiple solutions to your problem. **Avoid setting the font size to 0**;

Comment: Wow cool, I haven't found that post. I have just used the method with the comments, also posted by bažmegakapa. Actually I would like to accept both answers...

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to put comments into the markup, so list elements will not have white-space between them, so you do not need that hack anymore:

```
<ul><!--
    --><li>1</li><!--
    --><li>1</li><!--
    --><li>1</li><!--
--></ul>
```