# Div leaking through corner during transitions

Tags: css, html

I built a carousel with the following design:
http://jsfiddle.net/nj3xf/13/

Why is the div leaking through? Can somebody explain? and possibly offer a fix? I know it may have to do with the `overflow:hidden`

Comment: You should put the border/border-radius on the elements instead of the parent imo.

Comment: The problem with that is that the design looks really weird then.

Comment: Because of the red background? Just move the radius and border styles to the item and remove the red background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rendering round corners over CSS animations [is buggy](https://www.google.com/search?q=border%20radius%20clipping%20bug). A safe workaround is to animate the slides yourself.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nj3xf/18/

```
$("#move").click(function () {
    $('.slider').animate({left: "-=104px"});
});
```

**Edit:** Improved example: http://jsfiddle.net/nj3xf/19/. Avoid `display:inline-block` because it adds some unwanted margin between the slider items. See [display: inline-block extra margin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1833734/72478) and [Unwanted margin in inline-block list items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4969082/72478) for more info.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was spot on

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the bugginess if you set the containers to a higher z-index than the child div. It still affects the border property slightly, but it's much less noticeable.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.