# CSS display inline-block gaps in between elements

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
  <span class='box'>Content</span>
  <span class='box'>Content</span>
  <span class='box'>Content</span>
  <span class='box'>Content</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 960px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/58fmcabz/

When I [use](https://jsfiddle.net/g0c956ka/) `table-cell` in the display property the gaps disappear. I tried removing margin and padding using the `.box` class to no avail. Why are the gaps there?

Comment: This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By nature.

Here's a link for you:
https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is to add a float to your elements:

```
.box{width:300px; height:300px; display:inline-block; background-color:blue; float:left;}
```

That's it solved. The inline-block property is kinda creepy and I had to bear that for a whole day when I had the problem, a simple float solves the problem.

Someone asked the same question here- [Unwanted margin in inline-block list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969082/unwanted-margin-in-inline-block-list-items)

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
.box {
     width: 300px;
     height: 300px;
     background-color: blue;
     display: inline-block; 
     float:left;
}
```