# Is it okay to include markup after the closing </html> tag?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

Since [closing the html tag is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags), is it okay to include markup after a closing `</html>` tag?

An example of this exists with [Phil Haack's RouteDebugger library](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/routedebugger). Some sample output looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<h2>Index</h2>

</body>
</html>
<!-- Extra content after closing html tag! -->
<html>
<div id="haackroutedebugger" style="background-color: #fff;">
    <style>
        #haackroutedebugger, #haackroutedebugger td, #haackroutedebugger th {background-color: #fff; font-family: verdana, helvetica, san-serif; font-size: small;}
        #haackroutedebugger tr.header td, #haackroutedebugger tr.header th {background-color: #ffc;}
    </style>
    <hr style="width: 100%; border: solid 1px #000; margin:0; padding:0;" />
    <h1 style="margin: 0; padding: 4px; border-bottom: solid 1px #bbb; padding-left: 10px; font-size: 1.2em; background-color: #ffc;">Route Debugger</h1>
    <div id="main" style="margin-top:0; padding-top:0">
        <p style="font-size: .9em; padding-top:0">
            Type in a url in the address bar to see which defined routes match it. 
            A {*catchall} route is added to the list of routes automatically in 
            case none of your routes match.
        </p>
        <p style="font-size: .9em;">
            To generate URLs using routing, supply route values via the query string. example: <code>http://localhost:14230/?id=123</code>
        </p>
        <p><label style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em;">Matched Route</label>: {controller}/{action}/{id}</p>

        <div style="float: left;">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                <caption style="font-weight: bold;">Route Data</caption>
                <tr class="header"><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>
                    <tr><td>controller</td><td>Home&nbsp;</td></tr> <tr><td>action</td><td>Index&nbsp;</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="300">
                <caption style="font-weight: bold;">Data Tokens</caption>
                <tr class="header"><th>Key</th><th>Value</th></tr>

            </table>
        </div>
        <hr style="clear: both;" />
        <table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
            <caption style="font-weight: bold;">All Routes</caption>
            <tr class="header">
                <th>Matches Current Request</th>
                <th>Url</th>
                <th>Defaults</th>
                <th>Constraints</th>
                <th>DataTokens</th>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><span style="color: #c00">False</span></td><td>{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}</td><td>(null)</td><td>(empty)</td><td>(null)</td></tr><tr><td><span style="color: #0c0">True</span></td><td>{controller}/{action}/{id}</td><td>controller = Home, action = Index, id = UrlParameter.Optional</td><td>(empty)</td><td>(empty)</td></tr><tr><td><span style="color: #0c0">True</span></td><td>{*catchall}</td><td>(null)</td><td>(null)</td><td>(null)</td></tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <h3>Current Request Info</h3>
        <p>
            AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath is the portion of the request that Routing acts on.
        </p>
        <p><strong>AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath</strong>: ~/</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I notice that his appended markup begins with an `<html>` tag. Does the presence of this tag somehow validate the location of this content?

Comment: +1 Another (or a better question) is why Phil's library is doing that.  Looks odd.

Comment: I think he does it because then you don't have to add any boodstrap code to get it working.

Comment: Also, his route debugger is a diagnostic tool, not a production feature. Valid markup is a less of a concern when you're debugging.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not OK, but browsers are very forgiving with bad HTML.

Try http://validator.w3.org/ to see if a document is valid HTML or not (it isn't).

Answer (score 2):

Pages that are well-formed (correct sequencing, opening and closing of tags) load faster and make end-users happier.  It is good taste and good manners to use proper HTML, preferably when possible XHTML.  Do this, and you will win friends and influence people.

Comment: XHTML never left the incubator :}

Comment: Well-formed documents win every time. Don't do this? The browser will make choices. And they could be crappy.