# How to convert SQL value that has newlines into proper paragraphs <p> in HTML?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a text being returned from SQL that may have newlines in it.  However, since I'm putting the value in between `<p></p>` tags, it's ignoring the newlines.

For example if the text in SQL is actually this (with a CRLF between lines):

```
foobar car
carbar foo
```

The HTML code becomes:

```
<p>foobar car
carbar foo</p>
```

Which is just rendering as:

```
foobar car carbar foo
```

Ultimately it seems that I want to detect a newline then add the appropriate HTML such as:

```
<p>foobar car</p><p>carbar foo</p>
```

or even

```
<p>foobar car<br/><br/>carbar foo</p>
```

Should this be handled on the front end or in the SQL queries returning the data? It seems that it should be handled on the front end code (in my ASP.NET view) but if so, how?

I noticed that there a function in PHP to handle exactly this case: `nl2br` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) but unfortunately that doesn't help me :)

Comment: Just a reminder, if your using html5, the closing of the p tag is optional. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags so mystring.Replace("\n","<p>") might get you started

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's generally better to perform this kind of logic is your presentation code then your DB or middle-tier.

My Recommended approach would be to write some .net code to replace cr and lf with `<br/>` tags. The code itself is straightforward, here is an example that will emulate your php nl2br function:

```
string nl2br(string text)
{
    return text.Replace("\r", "<br/>").Replace("\n", "<br/>");
}
```

You could also perform this transform in SQL using [REPLACE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) and [CHAR()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx) although it is preferable to perform this kind of transform in the presentation layer, not the database layer.

The SQL approach would be:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(myStr, char(13), '<br/>'), CHAR(10), '<br/>')
```

This would replace `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` (cr and lf) with `<br/>` tags.

A third option would be to render your text at [preformatted text](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) using the `<pre>` tags although this is really only suitable for a narrow set of use-cases (such as displaying code as used here on StackOverflow)

e.g.

```
<pre>
    foobar car 
    carbar foo
</pre>
```

which would render like this:

```
foobar car 
carbar foo
```

keeping spaces and new lines intact.

Comment: Using `<pre>` is semantically wrong, bad for SEO, bad for screen readers, and should under no circumstances be used to format plain text.

Comment: I included that option for completeness but also because (although highly unlikely) it may be correct in the OPs actual scenario given the very little context. My recommendation remains to perform a transformation in the asp.net code.

Comment: I think you should emphasize which solution is better, otherwise OP might use the `<pre>` solution, because he is unaware of its the pitfalls.

Comment: This is partially working for me, but I am having issue that ASP.NET is HTML encoding the <br /> into &lt;br/&gt; when it's displayed. How can I prevent that?

Comment: @TMC It's difficult to say where that's coming from without seeing your code but this should help: `Server.HtmlDecode("&lt;br/&gt;");` Use `Server.HtmlDecode()` to decode the encoded html entities as they are displayed on the page.

Comment: Thanks, I"ve tried that without any luck. I've posted a separate question for this.

Comment: Depending on where the TEXT data is coming from and who/how it has been translated, CRLF might actually just imply a single break.  For us, we went with this to get the right formatting.  REPLACE(Description, char(13) + char(10), '<br/>')

Answer (score 2):

you can do this in sql server or in your application, to do this in sql server you can replace the carriage return char with this code:

```
select REPLACE(Comments,CHAR(13),' <br />') from Production.ProductReview
```

EDIT:

You can do this in a more elegant form handling in .Net code, through SqlDataReader, and changing the text:

```
        var target = "this is the line \r\n and this is another line";

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\r\n|\r|\n)+");

        string newText = regex.Replace(target, "<br />");
```

Comment: The approach to use regex is somewhat working. However, the issue is that ASP.NET is HTML encoding the `<br />` into `&lt;br/&gt;` when it's displayed. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

You should really be doing this in your web language (asp.net I guess), but if you must do it in SQL, here's how it's done:

MySQL:

```
SELECT REPLACE(column_name, "\r\n", "<br/>");
```

T-SQL (MS SQL Server):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(column_name, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '<br/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in SQL Server then one way is to use the `replace` function to replace char(13) + char(10) with

example

```
declare @s varchar(1000)

select @s = 'line1
line2'

select replace(@s,char(13) + char(10),'<br><br>')
```

### output

```
line1<br><br>line2
```

so in your case

```
select replace(ColumnName,char(13) + char(10),'<br><br>')
From SomeTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just process your data in ASP.NET. There is no reason to put that workload on the SQL server.

```
text = text.Replace("\r", "</p>\n<p>").Replace("\n","</p>\n<p>");
text = "<p>" + text + "</p>";
```

The above code will turn

```
foobar car
carbar foo
```

Into

```
<p>foobar car</p>
<p>carbar foo</p>
```