# HTML5: Where is the spec for which end tags are forbidden?

Tags: html, w3c

In HTML 4.01 certain end tags are ***forbidden***, that means it in not valid markup to have them, e.g.:

```
Invalid                     Valid
===================         =================
<BR/>                       <BR>
<BR></BR>      

<IMG src="..."/>            <IMG src="...">
<IMG ...></IMG>

<INPUT ... />               <INPUT ...>
<INPUT ...></INPUT>
```

In the HTML 4.01 specification the indication of an end tag being *optional* or *forbidden* is nicely summarized in [the index of elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html):

```
Name        Start Tag       End Tag
AREA                        F
BASE                        F
BASEFONT                    F
BODY        O               O
BR                          F
COL                         F
COLGROUP                    O
DD                          O
DT                          O
FRAME                       F
HEAD        O               O
HR                          F
HTML        O               O
IMG                         F
INPUT                       F
ISINDEX                     F
LI                          O
LINK                        F
META                        F
OPTION                      O
P                           O
PARAM                       F
TBODY       O               O
TD                          O
TFOOT                       O
TH                          O
THEAD                       O
TR                          O
```

Where is the HTML 5 equivalent of indicating which end tags are:

- required
- optional (implicit)
- forbidden

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When and how optional end tags should behave, in HTML5 spec:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements

> ### [8.1.2 Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements)
>
> [Void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements).
>
> ***Void Elements***
>
> - area
> - base
> - br
> - col
> - command
> - embed
> - hr
> - img
> - input
> - keygen
> - link
> - meta
> - param
> - source
> - track
> - wbr

A more concise form:

```
Element Type    Start Tag  End Tag
=============== =========  =========
Normal          -          O (some)
   html         O*         O*
   head         O*         O*
   body         -          O*
   li           -          O*
   dt           -          O*
   dd           -          O*
   p            -          O*
   rt           -          O*       
   rp           -          O*
   optgroup     -          O*
   option       -          O*
   colgroup     O*         O*
   thead        -          O*
   tbody        -          O*
   tfoot        -          O*
   tr           -          O*
   td           -          O*
   th           -          O*
   otherwise    -          -
Raw text        -          -
   script
   style
RCDATA          -          -
   textarea
   title
Void            -          F
   area
   base
   br
   col
   command
   embed
   hr
   img
   input
   keygen       
   link
   meta
   param
   source
   track
   wbr
Foreign         -          -          
   MathML
   SVG
```

Comment: Commenting to note that, as per the spec, self-closing void elements is *not required* but also *not forbidden*.

Comment: First, there doesn't appear to be a <command> element, at least not according to the HTML 5 spec linked to above. Secondly, it specifically states that "end tags must not be specified for void elements." Personally, I think this is stupid - not requiring it is acceptable but disallowing it is ridiculous, but that's just me. Am I reading the wrong spec? I should also mention that it does allow, e.g. <br/>, i.e. a self-closing void element. Just another instance of lack of consistency if you ask me.

Comment: @user1738579 The HTML5 spec is constantly changing, so a snapshot of a spec five years old is bound to be different than the current one. Elements come and go. However, I'm not sure why you think disallowing things like `</hr>` in code is "ridiculous".

Comment: I just discovered that the HTML5 version does not include obsolete and non-conforming elements such as `<frame>`. Perhaps that's appropriate, but I wanted to point it out in case someone was making a comprehensive list based upon the HTML5 list.