# An 'ul' element can never be a child of a 'p' element

Tags: html, html-lists

Why can we never have a `ul` element as the child of a `p` element?

I made a web page with the following code

```
<p> some text
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
.
.
.
</ul>
</p>
```

Here, the `ul` element is a child of the p element. However, in all major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer - all latest versions), it gets interpreted as follows

```
<p> some text</p>
<ul>
<li>...</li>
<li>...</li>
.
.
.
</ul>
<p></p>
```

I checked it by right-clicking on the `ul` element (in Chrome) and selecting the inspect element option. I saw it in Chrome, but the other two browsers also behaved in the same way (CSS selecter 'p ul' didn't work well).

Why is it so? Is there a general case in which such changes by the browser takes place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should ol/ul be inside <p> or outside?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Please check the [HTML specification](http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), which clearly states that putting lists in a paragraph element is forbidden, and also give some examples on what could be done:

> List elements (in particular, ol and ul elements) cannot be children of p elements. When a sentence contains a bulleted list, therefore, one might wonder how it should be marked up.
>
> For instance, this fantastic sentence has bullets relating to
>
> - wizards,
>
>   faster-than-light travel, and
>
>   telepathy,
>
> and is further discussed below.
>
> The solution is to realise that a paragraph, in HTML terms, is not a
>   logical concept, but a structural one. In the fantastic example above,
>   there are actually five paragraphs as defined by this speciication:
>   one before the list, one for each bullet, and one after the list.
>
> The markup for the above example could therefore be:
>
> ```
>   <p>For instance, this fantastic sentence has bullets relating to</p> 
>    <ul>
>        <li>wizards,  
>        <li>faster-than-light travel, and  
>        <li>telepathy, 
>    </ul>
>    <p>and is further discussed below.</p>
> ```
>
> Authors wishing to
>   conveniently style such "logical" paragraphs consisting of multiple
>   "structural" paragraphs can use the div element instead of the p
>   element.
>
> Thus for instance the above example could become the following:
>
> ```
>    <div>For instance, this fantastic sentence has bullets relating to
>    <ul>
>      <li>wizards,  
>      <li>faster-than-light travel, and  
>      <li>telepathy,
>    </ul> 
>    and is further discussed below.</div>
> ```
>
> This example still has
>   five structural paragraphs, but now the author can style just the div
>   instead of having to consider each part of the example separately.

Comment: I'm using trumbowyg and inside the editor chrome allows `ol` inside of `p`: https://i.imgur.com/1uyqtNO.png . Outside the editor's HTML, it has the same problem as OP. The editor gives me HTML code and I have to present it outside of it, so it breaks (because it has `ol` inside of `p`). How does the editor allow it in itself?

Comment: @hakermania The editor manipulates the DOM on the fly (through JS). Chrome reading HTML and building up the DOM from it is a different scenario.

Comment: The value (html code) of the editor is given within the html of the file itself (imagine `<textarea> <HTML CODE HERE> </textarea>`) and then the editor's js code is called upon the `textarea` element. This means that the browser has the 1st say on the html code within the textarea and _then_ the editor. So if chrome has converted `<p><ol>...</ol></p>` to `<p></p><ol>...</ol>` then the editor will see the latter value and have no knowledge of the former. I think something else happens under the hood but I can't find it.

Comment: @hakermania Whatever is inside the textarea tag, it will not be validated as HTML by the browser - it is treated as an ordinary string.

Comment: According to whatwg.org, this is indeed the correct answer. Unfortunately MDN is sending a confusing message with their own `ul/ol` description stating that `Permitted parents: Any element that accepts flow content.` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) The list of flow content elements contains `p` as well.  Very confusing.

Answer (score 5):

It has always been a rule in HTML that a `p` element can contain only text and text-level markup, not a list for example. Therefore, browsers imply a closing `</p>` tag when a `p` element is open and a start tag for a block level element, like `<ul>`, is encountered. In your example, the `</p>` tag after `</ul>` is homeless and normally ignored.

Answer (score 4):

`<p>` can have only inline elements as childs and no block elements (see, e.g, at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/p)). `<ul>` on the other hand is a block level element ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/ul))!

The reason why browser interpret your code as you have seen lies in the HTML5 parsing spec. The spec lists an example very much like your own: [whatwg link](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).

Another interesting related question might be this: [HTML: Include, or exclude, optional closing tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags)