# Checkboxes won't select when inside a Collapsed List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am working on making a list of options that can be selected with checkboxes. Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LESTN/2`enter code here`

I am able to create functioning checkboxes out side of the list as shown but the checkboxes associated with list elements are not clickable. 
Any suggestions as to how i can resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: cleared out the in text code and added a fiddle.

Comment: I don't see you closing the inner <ul> tag, I only see one being closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .click( function(event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        return false;
    })
```

Remove return false;

http://jsfiddle.net/qdcH7/2/

Also this doesn't look right: `<li>Hot Cups<ul>`

Also, UL shouldn't be inside a P tag: [ul element can never be a child of p element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601345/ul-element-can-never-be-a-child-of-p-element)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I was able to replicate the issue.  The issue is the return false statement.

```
    $('#expList').find('li:has(ul)').click( function(event) {
        if (this == event.target) {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
            $(this).children('ul').toggle('medium');
        }
        return false;
    })
```

When you click a checkbox in the list, the checkbox is considered the event target, but "this" is the actual dropdown eg #expList.  It is returning false unless (this == event.target), which is not the case on the checkboxes.

Remove return false, or change the way that if statement handles the value.

Also just as a general rule of thumb, close all your tags and properly indent your html.  Your HTML is a bit funky, a lot of it is formatted oddly.  Maybe something like this?

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<div id="listContainer">
    <div id="expList">
        Hot Cups
             <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="Sample" value="val 1">Title 1</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="Sample" value="val 2">Title 2</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="Sample" value="val 3">Title 3</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="Sample" value="val 4">Title 4</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="Sample" value="val 5">Title 5</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="Sample" value="val 6">Title 6</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="Sample" value="val 7">Title 7</li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```