# Brackets live preview not working due to syntax error using emmet extension

Tags: emmet, adobe-brackets, live-preview

**Using emmet extension to expand html tag abbreviations in Brackets when live preview is active, it doesn't update and shows**

> *Live Preview (not working due to syntax error)*

If for example I write:

```
ul>li*3
```

and press tab it expands into

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

and Brackets stop its live preview update.

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the `<ul>` inside a `<p>` tag? Technically that isn't legal HTML – for example see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10601411/1172352). Lists can be inside a div, but not a paragraph.

If that's not the problem, could you post a code snippet that shows where you're inserting the `<ul>`?