# Removing only the outer html element from a HTML code section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove outer HTML element from a code snippet to get the content inside including other html elements.

that is,

consider the below code

```
<p> My Paragraph 
   <ul>Mylist
     <li>Item1</li>
     <li>Item2</li>
   </ul>
</p>
```

I want to get the output displayed as below

```
My Paragraph 
       <ul>Mylist
           <li>Item1</li>
           <li>Item2</li>
       </ul>
```

Is this possible ??

Comment: Please provide us with some code, and could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Your code and desired output is same. What is ur query ?

Comment: sorry guys, by mistake i saved the code without intending the code.  Now i have edited the question. please have a look and provide some solution.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.unwrap()` along with `.contents()` to target all the contents in it:

```
 $('p').contents().unwrap();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/doywr2kv/)**

Comment: Helo Milind, i need to get the inner html elements as it is. donot want to remove or apply inner tags. :) could it be possible? Thank you

Comment: @Milin plus one, but his markup is not right may be it will cuase problem

Comment: @A.B: indeed. p tags are not suppose to have ul element. here is why http://stackoverflow.com/a/10601411/1719752

Comment: @MonuThomas: it does not remove any contents. its just unwrapping the parent. see the demo.

Comment: ok if so i can change the code to '<div> My Div 
<ul> My List
<li>Item1</li> 
<li>Item2</li> </ul> </div>' Then I need Output as 'My Div <ul> My List <li>Item1</li> <li>Item2</li> </ul>'.

Comment: in that case, you will have to use `$('div').contents().unwrap(); `

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: sir, i dont want to get output in formatted form. just display the <ul> <li> tags inside <div> as it is. can we do so ?

Comment: well it is not clear what are you asking now. are you looking for indented format.

Answer (score 0):

ul elements are not legally allowed inside `p' elements.

you can unwrap() function to do this [Refrence](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code ul inside p will not work as expected when using

```
$('p').contents().unwrap();
```

As suggest by A.B. Use div instead of p, than try

```
$('div').contents().unwrap();
```