# How do i replace an element with the children it contains?

Tags: jquery

To remove the default `<p>` tag from tinyMCE content, I create a `div` that stores the content coming from tinyMCE (includes `<p>` tags). Then, by using find method `find('p:first').html()` I retrieve the html text inside the tag. It works great, I can get rid of `<p>` tags. However, with this approach, for example, the list tags `ul` are just lost in the content. I have not try, but other html tags might also get lost. Do you see any problems with my code below:

```
var newcontent = tinymce.get('textarea_1').getContent();
//this returns a p tag that can have hold any content: 
//<p>content goes here <ul><li>a</li></ul>...</p>

var mydiv = $("<div>").html(newcontent);

newcontent =  mydiv.find('p:first').html();
//here I just want to get rid of <p> tag
//however I also got <ul> list items removed.
```

**UPDATE**

I tried the following code, but I got the innerHtml of `mydiv` empty:

```
 var postcontent = tinymce.get('inputPostDetails').getContent();

 var mydiv = $("<div>").html(postcontent);
 mydiv.replaceWith(mydiv.children());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to lack of rep as of now, I am unable to post question in the comments.

From what I understand of your html structure, if you remove the `<p>` tags, your content in it will be gone as well.

```
<div>
  <p> <!-- removing this will be removing its content too -->
    <ul>
      <li>#1</liv>
      <li>#2</liv>
    </ul>
  </p>
</div>
```

Are you intending to remove the `<p>` tag but not its content?
Could you explain more on what you are trying to do? :)

**EDIT**: [HTML specifies that `<ul>` tags are not to be inside of `<p>` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601345/ul-element-can-never-be-a-child-of-p-element)

I have replaced `<p>` with `<div>` and I came up with this
**Javascript:**

```
// Simulating loading contents into the myDiv
function getContent(){
    return "<div id='removeMe'><ul><li>#1</li><li>#2</li></ul></div>";
}
var postcontent = getContent();
var mydiv = $("div").html(postcontent); // jQuery selector for tags do not need <> signs

// Removing P tag but keep contents
function removeP(){
    var replaceThisElement = mydiv.find("#removeMe");
    var contents = replaceThisElement.html();
    $("div > #removeMe").replaceWith(contents + "<div>element removed!</div>");
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<button onclick="removeP()">Remove P tag but keep contents</button>

<div>
</div>
```

[**Working example here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxyyXQ?editors=101)

Comment: exactly, I am trying to remove p tag but keep its content. Actually it keeps its content but when I have a list item inside p, then it just removes that part and keeps the other text.

Comment: I've just thought of it, you cannot put `<ul>` inside of `<p>`, refer to this [SO post about it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601345/ul-element-can-never-be-a-child-of-p-element)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, https://jsfiddle.net/7denp9h0/

```
var p = $('#removeMe');
p.replaceWith(p.children())
```

Comment: could you please check the updated code? I think it will still keep `<p>` tag. I just need its content. I can access its content but it discards other html tags inside the content.

Comment: Your issue is that your putting elements inside a `<p>`. Which is [incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397852/why-p-tag-cant-contain-div-tag-inside-it). i.e. there is not guaranteed behavior. The fiddle works, substituting a `<p>` for a  `<div>`, check the updated fiddle.