# nth-last-child selector not working

Tags: css

I have this html:

```
<div class="leading-4">
<h2>title</h2>
<p>one para</p>
<p>Maybe another para</p>
<p><ul><li>.....</li></ul></p>
<h4>text</h4>
</div>
```

I want to edit the p that has the ul in it -

I thought about

```
.leading-4 p:nth-last-child(1){
}
```

and

```
.leading-4:nth-last-child(1){
}
```

but it doesn't' work either (though I didn't think it would)

What am i doing wrong please

Comment: Use `:last-of-type` instead.

Comment: Or more probably `p:has(ul)`. But your HTML is invalid, an UL element can't be in a P element.

Comment: Darn -  you''re right. Yes, blooming tired this morning - need a strong coffee! that was to illustrate - actually its a load of links and texts and images....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a `<ul>` inside a `<p>` tag! So when you put `<p><ul></ul></p>`, the browser considers it as `<p></p><ul></ul>`.

So technically, there's and cannot be `<ul>` inside a `<p>` so your CSS selector **never ever** selects an element under any case in HTML.

So, consider changing the element to `<div>` instead.

**Proof:**

```css
p {color: red;}
ul {color: blue;}
p ul {color: green;}
```

```html
<p>This is para</p>
<p>
  The next UL element will be kicked out of P. Before UL.
  <ul><li>This is LI inside UL inside P</li></ul>
  After UL. And this becomes normal text under the body, and not under P.
</p>
<ul><li>This is LI inside UL</li></ul>
```

**References:**

- [ul element can never be a child of p element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601345/ul-element-can-never-be-a-child-of-p-element)
- [is it acceptable to put a UL inside of a paragraph??](http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/153770-acceptable-put-ul-inside-paragraph)

**Solution:**

The solution for selecting the last `<p>` for you would be:

```
p:last-of-type { /* rules */}
```

Comment: You are right about the structure. You might want to add that, in order to select the last `p` in his code, which isn't the last-child of the parent, he'll need to use `:nth-last-of-type(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type).

But as Praveen says you should fix your HTML. Use the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) when in doubt.

Comment: many thanks Praveen. Code fixed and solution works once the (1) is inserted into the brackets