# Why won't this CSS selector work for <li> when inside <p> tag?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm revising for my exam, going over answering some past questions without the markscheme. I am confused on this:

For the following rule, explain the effect and which elements will be affected:

```
p ul li {
   color:blue;
}
```

I wrote up some HTML on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2nkmzgv2/

It's here anyway:

```
<p>
  <ul>
      <li>Should this be blue?</li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

So nothing happens to the text. I would have thought it changes blue, but is nothing actually meant to happen and the purpose of the question was to throw you off or is my syntax/method wrong in the HTML content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because ol/ul items aren't allowed inside of p elements.

[Should ol/ul be inside <p> or outside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681481/should-ol-ul-be-inside-p-or-outside)

Seems like a trick question for your exam then. Most likely you will want to brush up on the HTML spec since the question isn't truly based on CSS knowledge alone.

You are getting the described behavior because [`<p>` cannot contain block-level elements such as `<ul>` or `<ol>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1). The browser (e.g., Chrome) knows this is not possible and thus try to handle your illegal structure by placing your block element in between two paragraphs:

[image]

Because of this, the rule you have declared for that `li` does not apply.

```css
p ul li {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Hello
  <ul>
    <li>I'm never blue.</li>
  </ul>
  Goodbye
</p>
```

Other trick questions could be:

```
a a { color:red }
p p { color:blue; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is invalid since you [cannot have list inside paragraph tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601345/ul-element-can-never-be-a-child-of-p-element).

That means that the CSS will also never be applied to the `li` element. The correct CSS would be just:

```
ul li {
    color: blue;
}
```

with this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Should this be blue?</li>
</ul>
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nkmzgv2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

"List elements (in particular, ol and ul elements) cannot be children of p elements. When a sentence contains a bulleted list." by [HTML specification](http://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-p-element)

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to help you to arise your content quality