# Styling a table layout fixed & fixed width columns + colspan

Tags: css, html-table

I have the following layout.

```
<style>
   table { width: 200px; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed; }
   .a { width:10px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis }
   .b { width:190px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis }
</style>

<table border="1" style="">
    <tr>         
        <td colspan="2">Some content header goes in here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a">This cells has more content</td>
        <td class="b">Less content here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to set a fixed table layout and have a fixed width on each column, however, since I have `colspan` above the fixed columns, then I'm not able to set the width. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could add a couple of [`col`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/col) tags after the opening `<table>` tag and set the width on those:

```
<style>
   table { width: 200px; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed; }
   .a { overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis }
   .b { overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis }
   .cola { width: 10px; }
   .colb { width: 190px; }
</style>

<table border="1" style="">
    <col class="cola" />
    <col class="colb" />
    <tr>         
        <td colspan="2">Some content header goes in here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a">This cells has more content</td>
        <td class="b">Less content here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: that `col` should really be closed

Comment: Depends on your DOCTYPE. It's perfectly valid HTML5, which is what I'm going for these days.

Comment: hmm... for some reason I thought they should be self-closed in XHTML and *optionally* self-closed in HTML (i.e. not to be closed with a `</col>`) - however http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags begs to differ. `</tr>` and `</td>` are optional though!

Comment: Anyway to do this with less HTML markup? I am trying to implement this within an existing site, so it would be problematic to have to go back through hundreds of pages and insert `<col>` tags

Comment: I'm not aware of a way, but if you find one, please feel free to share.

Comment: PS col was depreciated in html4 and is obsolete in html5.

Comment: `<col>` and `<colgroup>` are still valid in both HTML4 and HTML5, but many of the attributes on `<col>` (e.g., `<col align="">`) were deprecated in HTML4 and made obsolete in HTML5. The syntax above is valid in HTML4 and HTML5, though. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col), [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-col-element), [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-COL).