# Internet Explorer text above absolute positioned link

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, anchor

I have created a list of boxes with text inside that are clickable, however IE sets the text above the link, so when hovering over the text it prioritizes it making the link no longer work. Chrome + Firefox work as intended.

Also I would like to see if a fix is possible without the use of javascript or jQuery, if possible. I also need it to support IE8+.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X5T5H/2/).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <ul class="container">
            <li class="optionBox"> <i class="reporting"></i>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis
                    tortor egestas massa dignissim eu auctor turpis rutrum. Morbi suscipit
                    dictum lacinia.</p>
              </li>
                <li class="optionBox"> <i class="reporting"></i>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis
                        tortor egestas massa dignissim eu auctor turpis rutrum. Morbi suscipit
                        dictum lacinia.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="optionBox"> <i class="reporting"></i>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>

                    <p>CLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis
                        tortor egestas massa dignissim eu auctor turpis rutrum. Morbi suscipit
                        dictum lacinia.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="optionBox"> <i class="reporting"></i>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis
                        tortor egestas massa dignissim eu auctor turpis rutrum. Morbi suscipit
                        dictum lacinia.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="optionBox"> <i class="reporting"></i>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis
                        tortor egestas massa dignissim eu auctor turpis rutrum. Morbi suscipit
                        dictum lacinia.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="optionBox"> <i class="reporting"></i>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis
                        tortor egestas massa dignissim eu auctor turpis rutrum. Morbi suscipit
                        dictum lacinia.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="optionBox"> <i class="reporting"></i>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis
                        tortor egestas massa dignissim eu auctor turpis rutrum. Morbi suscipit
                        dictum lacinia.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="optionBox"> <i class="reporting"></i>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>

                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis
                        tortor egestas massa dignissim eu auctor turpis rutrum. Morbi suscipit
                        dictum lacinia.</p>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1000px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 0;
}
.optionBox {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    height: 125px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0.3em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em 2em 0.5em;
    color: #555;
    background: transparent;
    border: solid 1px #DDD;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.reporting {
    position: absolute;
    background:url('http://s13.postimage.org/w73u674ur/icon.png') no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 340px;
    height: 115px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 3.8em;
    color: #08C;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
p {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 1.6em 0 0 3.8em;
}
body {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: li do not need to be closed, they are also not the cause. thanks for letting me know though.

Comment: Your first optionBox li is NOT closed.

Comment: Yea, they do. Why wouldn't they? FF and Chrome might fix your missing tags, but IE will not which WILL lead to bugs that leave you shaking your head.

Comment: See this question why they are optional. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags)

Comment: Interesting. I've still run into issues in IE when missing a closing tag. I'd suggest it good practice to use them.

Comment: [Per the HTML5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html), `<li>` elements do not need to have a matching `</li>` **if it is immediately followed by the next `<li>`, or by the `</ul>`**. @KyleNeedham - Having other elements, then, would necessitate that you have a closing tag. Besides, what will it hurt to be consistent with the rest of your `<li>`s?

Comment: @Shauna i have now corrected it, i was just saying that will not cause my problem.

Comment: @KyleNeedham - Given that the spec says it needs to be closed in your circumstance, how do you know it isn't the cause of your problem until you actually close it?

Comment: @PerfectDark When you hover over any text within the <p></p> tag the link no longer works (notice the text:underline on the the anchor hover being deselected when doing so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in IE with absolute positioned anchor elements.

The most common workaround is to set a background to the anchor. However, since you obviously don't want the link to hide the text below it, you'll need to set a transparent background image. In order to do that, I usually prefer to set the background to an existing path that would serve as an invalid image.

For example:

```css
a {
    position:absolute;
    /* ... */
    background:url('about:blank');
}
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X5T5H/6/)**

Alternatively, you can also create an actual transparent image and set it as the background.