# Why can't I add more paragraphs to this HTML document?

Tags: html, css

I've finished my HTML and CSS course at Codecademy and now I want to study Python.

Before I do, I would like to build a small website about the things I'm about to learn, just to practice my HTML and CSS skills.

I'm having trouble, because I can't add more content below my HTML file and don't know why.

Here is the HTML (also on http://pastebin.com/br4W1YGL):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Python</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="texto">
            <h2>Welcome to the Flying Circus</h2>
            <p>Python is a powerful, flexible programming language you can use in web/Internet development, to write 
            desktop graphical user interfaces (GUIs), create games, and much more. Python is:</p>
            <ul>
            <li><strong>High-level</strong>, meaning reading and writing Python is really easy—it looks a lot like regular English!</li>
            <li><strong>Interpreted</strong>, meaning you don't need a compiler to write and run Python! You can write it here at Codecademy 
            or even on your own computer (many are shipped with the Python interpreter built in—we'll get to the interpreter later in this lesson).</li>
            <li><strong>Object-oriented</strong>, meaning it allows users to manipulate data structures called <strong>objects</strong> in order to build and execute programs. 
            We'll learn more about objects later.</li>
            <li><strong>Fun to use</strong>. Python is named after Monty Python's Flying Circus, and example code and tutorials 
            often refer to the show and include jokes in order to make learning the language more interesting.</li>
            </ul>
            <p>This course assumes no previous knowledge of Python in particular or programming/computer science in general.</p>

            <div id="instrucoes">
            <h4>INSTRUCTIONS</h4>
            <p>Ready to learn Python? Click Save & Submit Code to continue!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="hint">
            <h4>Hint</h4>
            <p>If the loading bar fills but doesn't fade away, try refreshing the page.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a id="voltar" href="#">[ voltar ]</a>
        <div class="codigo">
            print "Welcome to Python!"
        </div>
        <p>oi<p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS (http://pastebin.com/48XvxedE):

```
html, body, form, fieldset, legend {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
fieldset,img {
    border: 0;
}
legend{
    color: #000;
}
sup {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
sub {
    vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: normal;
}
input, textarea, select {
    font-size: 110%;
    line-height: 1.1;
}
abbr, acronym {
    border-bottom: .1em dotted;
    cursor: help;
}

/*o meu código começa aqui, o código acima é um reset*/
/*fonte do reset: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-reset/ */

html {
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.95em;
    color: #424242;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
body {

}
.texto {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 550px;
}
#instrucoes {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    width: 536px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #585858;
    border: 2px solid #D8D8D8;
}
#hint {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    width: 536px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #585858;
    border: 2px solid #D8D8D8;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.codigo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 630px;
    top: 65px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 676px;
    height: 420px;
    background-color: #e6efc2;
    color: #264409;
    border: 2px solid #c6d880;
    font-family: mono;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
#voltar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1275px;
    top: 25px;
    color: #585858;
}
a:link {text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {text-decoration: none;}
a:hover {background-color: #F2F2F2; }
a:active {text-decoration: none;}
hr {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #D8D8D8;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    height: 2px;
}
```

Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MBMf2/

Does someone here know why I can't add more paragraphs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You can](http://jsfiddle.net/MBMf2/4/).

The `<p>` elements have to be inside the main, first `div` with the class `texto`, otherwise, just like your "oi" text,* it'll appear outside the document flow because of the CSS you took from [Codeacademy's site](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/introduction-to-python-6WeG3/0/1).

Also, when used in the context you put it in, this isn't a very good practice for your wrapper:

```
.texto {
    position: absolute;
}
```

That could cause a multitude of confusion for you down the line and doesn't have a purpose when taken out of context from Codeacademy's site (where it's a left side-bar).

<sub>* You forgot to close the `</p>` element for "oi", but don't worry it happens to the most experienced developers too! In fact, [it shouldn't matter to the layout and browser rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags), but I am from the school of thought that it's more robust and future-proof code if all elements that aren't self-closing are closed.</sub>