# List lost its bullets

Tags: html, css, html-lists, multiple-columns, bulletedlist

Why when i split an `ul` into two columns it is losing its bullets??
HTML:

```
<ul class="with-columns">
    <li>Ringo
    <li>George
    <li>John
    <li>Paul
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.with-columns{
    -moz-columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2; 
    -o-columns: 2;
    columns: 2;  
    list-style-type:circle; /* Not works! */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4xKea/

Comment: @Ruddy i knew it must be somewhere!..

Comment: I guess Alek has given right answer. But one note - I think you should close `<li>` tag with `</li>`, for example, `<li>Ringo</li>`.

Comment: @IgorReshetnikov , not exactly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3008735/1206613

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RL7h4/)

Answer (score 3):

Just add `list-style-position: inside;` inside `ul.with-columns` css

Comment: You are, unfortunately, a bit late