# Transition not working in Firefox and IE, only in chrome

Tags: html, css

I've got a navigation menu that uses the CSS3 transition property for a nice effect, but it doesn't work in Firefox. I've tried a Google search and tried with no success the suggestions to similar problems other people had, can anyone help please?
Thanks in advance for any help and/or suggestions.

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/number8pie/568fZ/5/

Here's the HTML:

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <p class="nav-hvr-init">Navigate</p>
    <ul> <!-- no closing tag on <li> so that the whitespace between elements is removed-->
        <li id="about-us">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text sr-only">about us</span>
        <li id="products">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text sr-only">products</span>
        <li id="the-team">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text sr-only">the team</span>
        <li id="environment">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text sr-only">environment</span>
        <li id="contact">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"></a>
            <span class="nav-text sr-only">contact</span>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}

#nav-row {
  background-color: #CCFFCC;
}

#nav-col {
  height: 56px;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-color: #336600;
}

.main-nav {
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #336600;
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  height: 56px;
  width: 56px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 21px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#about-us a {
  background: #66CC66 url('http://s10.postimg.org/xqx00ofzp/about_us.png') no-repeat center;
}

#about-us a:hover {
  background: #66CC66 url('http://s10.postimg.org/9borzmh2t/about_us_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in;
}

#about-us a:active {
  background: #66CC66 url('http://s10.postimg.org/ekjsxhzhx/about_us_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

#products a {
  background: #33CC33 url('http://s10.postimg.org/defsypb79/products.png') no-repeat center;
}

#products a:hover {
  background: #33CC33 url('http://s10.postimg.org/y2j1r6lth/products_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in;
}

#products a:active {
  background: #33CC33 url('http://s10.postimg.org/6p99iopv9/products_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

#the-team a{
  background: #339900 url('http://s10.postimg.org/4sh4ruol1/the_team.png') no-repeat center;
}

#the-team a:hover {
  background: #339900 url('http://s10.postimg.org/buf2e1s6t/the_team_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in;
}

#the-team a:active {
  background: #339900 url('http://s10.postimg.org/wd9yj4645/the_team_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

#environment a {
  background: #006600 url('http://s10.postimg.org/gb7fcq6et/environment.png') no-repeat center;
}

#environment a:hover {
  background: #006600 url('http://s10.postimg.org/n47s8zx85/environment_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in;
}

#environment a:active {
  background: #006600 url('http://s10.postimg.org/6y6u8m2np/environment_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

#contact a {
  background: #003300 url('http://s10.postimg.org/9pq3z816d/contact.png') no-repeat center;
}

#contact a:hover {
  background: #003300 url('http://s10.postimg.org/udordymet/contact_hover.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 350ms ease-in;
  transition: all 350ms ease-in;
}

#contact a:active {
  background: #003300 url('http://s10.postimg.org/4scje3z79/contact_active.png') no-repeat center;
  -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
  transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

.main-nav > ul {
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  padding: 0;
}

li > svg {
  margin: 9% 0 0 11%;
}

li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 0;
  height: 56px;
  z-index:2;
}

.nav-text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: 'Arial Black';
  font-size: 21px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.nav-hvr-init {
  color: #76B766;
  font-family: 'Arial Black';
  font-size: 21px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 100%;
  margin-right: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 280px;
  bottom: 0px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.txt-arrows {
  font-family: 'Arrows';
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: none;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-left: 4px;
}
```

And the jQuery:

```
$( ".nav-link" ).hover(
  function() {
    var ntext = $( this ).siblings( "span" ).html();   
          $( ".nav-hvr-init" )
          .stop()
          .animate({right: '0px'},200,function() {
              $(this).html(ntext).animate({right:'280px'},200);
          });
  }, function() {
      $( ".nav-hvr-init" )
            .stop()
            .animate({right: '0px'},200,function() {
                $(this).html('Navigate').animate({right:'280px'},200);
            });
  }
);
```

Comment: As an aside, the part `<!-- no closing tag on <li> so that the whitespace between elements is removed-->` is a terrible terrible approach to coding, and invalidates your HTML leading to broken functionality. Float your `li` or `font-size:0` your `ul` to solve this, dont ignore the HTML spec!

Comment: Wasn't really keen on using it to begin with so I won't need persuading not to use it. I'll be sure to change it before I take it out of the development stage. Thanks.

Comment: No, it is perfectly fine to not close li tags. For some tags like li the closing is optional when it is semantically clear. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect I assume is missing is the crossfading of the button images. Only Chrome actually transitions `background` with a crossfade. If you want this effect everywhere, you'll have to use a more "standard" approach by having a new element (with the hover background) fade in and out via `opacity` on top of the normal button. You can use pseudo-elements to do this.

Comment: +1! Also you could animate the border color from transparent to white

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this has got me part of the way there. I've got the first two stages initial and hover to work in IE, but the click state only works in chrome and Firefox though doesn't fade, and doesn't not work in IE (11).