# How to remove the space between two <span> tags?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have a list of spans. In the HTML file, it is nice to list these `<span>` tags in different lines for readability and maintenance as follows:

```
<span><a href="some link">A link</a></span>
<span><a href="some link">A link</a></span>
<span><a href="some link">A link</a></span>
<span><a href="some link">A link</a></span>
<span><a href="some link">A link</a></span>
```

However, these create a space between these `<span>` tags. I am wondering if there is any CSS or other way to remove this space between two `<span>` tags without putting all above spans in one line without any space in between?

Note that we assume that the above html structure cannot change.

Thanks and regards.

**-------- UPDATE ------------**

After reading dfsq's solution and other related posts, I feel there is no perfect answer. It really **depends on the specific need**. dfsq's solution is clever and should work but get things over complicated.

What I have regarding the specific need is having a border between two spans and the space between the border and span should be the same. For my particular need, I found the two acceptable solutions too:

1. Use CSS to float span
2. Add an extra space as follows: `<span><a href="some link">A link</a>&nbsp;</span>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: You know that newlines are counted as spaces in HTML right?

Comment: Make the parent `font-size: 0;` and the `span` `font-size` to what you want. This will fix it.

Comment: The question I linked above has some very thorough answers, I recommend reading those.

Comment: Yes, there is no perfect solution. In future there should be pure CSS mechanism to control white space behavior, but at the moment there is none.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I usually set `font-size` of the parent container to zero, which  makes white spaces causing gaps to disappear. You then just need to set font-size back to necessary value for spans, for example:

```
.container {
    font-size: 0;     // whitespaces go away
}
.container span {
    font-size: 16px;  // spans text please stay
    background: #DDD;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/we9bvrpe/

Comment: +1 for you have made it so clever.

Comment: Im curious still i'm seeing some spaces around there hope i don't have night blidness

Comment: @Benjamin Interesting, what browser is it?

Comment: using chrome the latest

Comment: @Benjamin Are you sure your not just seeing the padding and thinking its white spaces? (I'm using latest Chrome and its fine)

Comment: Iam not seeing any spaces around span but some spaces around the text. the underline breaks if i would more precise

Comment: Hey ma apology didn't noticed the padding in style.

Comment: @Benjamin Thought that might be it :)

Comment: @Ruddy yep thats embracing.

Comment: However I checked browsers, and in fact there is one that still have gaps: IE7. But I wouldn't care about this one.

Comment: @dfsq ma apologies dude didn't noticed the padding written in style. Thats embracing.:(

Answer (score 7):

Although [**the solution suggesting to change parent font size is a better solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25667514/1257652), this is something I have found to help:

```
<span><a href="some link">A link</a></span><span>
      <a href="some link">A link</a></span><span>
      <a href="some link">A link</a></span><span>
      <a href="some link">A link</a></span><span>
      <a href="some link">A link</a></span>
```

Explanation : remove the white space between open and closing tags of the sibling span elements

Comment: Explanation of the downvote, please. This is a valid and appropriate answer.

Comment: Upvoted. This is actually quite a nice alternative solution. Might not be suitable when you have strict formatting rules, but it serves the purpose well.

Answer (score 2):

Try to write all your `span` in inline as follows

```
<span><a href="some link">A link</a></span><span><a href="some link">A link</a></span><span><a href="some link">A link</a></span><span><a href="some link">A link</a></span><span><a href="some link">A link</a></span>
```

Comment: Similar to Dan's answer, while this is a valid answer the OP has asked for a way to do this without putting all the `span`s on one line.

Comment: Im seeing no answer like this here.

Comment: That'll be because Dan deleted his ;)

Comment: So you want to delete ma answer too.

Comment: Not necessarily, just noting that while this does work the OP asked for another way of tackling the problem.

Comment: Thats great. Feeling comfort.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not work for your situation, but you can use elements like `<li> and <dl><dt><dd>` which have an optional closing tag. The browser adds the closing tag for you and also has the effect of removing white space!

Reference - [HTML: Include, or exclude, optional closing tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags)

Check this Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/by0sw7kc/

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="some link">A link</a>
  <li><a href="some link">A link</a>
  <li><a href="some link">A link</a>
  <li><a href="some link">A link</a>
  <li><a href="some link">A link</a>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
  background: red;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  background: deepSkyBlue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Michael, thanks for chiming in. I understand your solution should work too. I simply don't want to change the html structure. I also added an  update regarding other solutions.

Answer (score -3):

You can remove padding from padding and margin from all the spans I would recommend adding a class to these spans in case you DO NOT want to do them to all others throughout your site.

span {padding:0;margin:0;}

with class

span .className {padding:0;margin:0;}

Comment: this wont work should try before you answer

Comment: Hi @pcproff. if your answer is not accepted, you can delete the whole answer and the rating you lost with minus points will be restored back to you, as if you didn't answer at all. Sometimes it is difficult to correct an already negatively voted answer, so this will probably be a better solution for you.

Answer (score -4):

Try

```
.container span {
   margin-left:-3px;
}
```

Comment: Adding a negative margin to all spans is a bad design decision. Even doing this conditionally is a bad design decision. This does not resolve the problem, it attempts to hide it through a hack that may not work across all browsers