# Remove a white space between spans

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have spans setup as so..

```
<span class='Main'>
   <span id='id1'>some</span> <span id='id2'>words</span>
</span> 
<span>.</span>
```

This outputs

> some words .

Is there a way to remove the space before the period & keep the rest of the spaces intact?

I've tried `trim()` but that removes all spaces in my string; there are many words preceding (each within a span) that i do not want effected.

Is there a way to 'target' that particular space?

Ed: I can edit the HTML & remove the white space, but i want to do it programmatically.

Comment: Are you programmatically generating the `<span>` elements?

Answer (score 2):

Since [`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) elements are `inline` elements by default, the white space between them will be respected (displayed). One way to avoid this is to remove the undesired white space between the elements in your HTML code:

```html
<span class='Main'><span id='id1'>some</span> <span id='id2'>words</span></span><span>.</span>
```

---

### Edit

If you don't want to alter the HTML code, maybe you can use CSS to simulate spaces between words.

In the example below, I'm setting the `font-size` for the container to zero to hide white space, then setting the `font-size` of `<span>` elements to a readable size (a method posted [by thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements#answer-5078297) and [by dsfq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667401/how-to-remove-the-space-between-two-span-tags#answer-25667514)). Then I'm adding some margin before each `<span>` that is not the first or last child.

Admittedly, this method is not very reliable, especially if you can't predict whether there will be a period or not.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
.container span {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: #DDD;
}
.container span:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 0 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>some</span>
  <span>words</span>
  <span>go</span>
  <span>here</span>
  <span>.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @boomshanka exactly just remove the space in the HTML as posted above.

Comment: Yes, this is what i want to do - but programmatically via jQuery / js; not by editing the HTML.

Comment: @showdev Yes, i am & you're right; i tried this originally but cannot work out where the space is coming from. It seems to appear when i `wrapAll()` my id spans with the `Main` class...

Comment: Hm, maybe you can include the generating code in your question. That might help find a more efficient and reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although not neat I decided to code this with some jquery and js:

```
var get = "";
var array = [];
var i = 0;
var concat = "";
var str;

function doAction() {
    $("span").each(function (index, value) {

        if (index != 0) {

            get = $(this).text() + " ";
            array[index] = get;
            if (array[index].trim() == '.') {

                array[index] = array[index - 1].trim() + array[index];
                array[index - 1] = "";


            }
        }
    });
    $("span").each(function (index, value) {

        if (index != 0) {
            $(this).text(array[index]);
        }

    });
}
doAction();
```

and here is the fiddle. I added more spans to it and it works again. Hope it is good, url: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/kphe5fbL/4/