# How to remove white space from both sides of span?

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code:

```css
.title span {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT Pro Condensed', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Gill Sans';
}
.title .big {
  font-size: 250px;
}

.title .small {
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title flex">
  <span class="big">1</span>
  <span class="small">st</span>
</div>
```

How to remove the massive white space around the first span?

This is what I want to accomplish:
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asttd.png)

But this is what I have due to that massive white space:
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XscJY.png)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vmn3bz0k/

Comment: I know that I can make them closer by changing position and other things. But I'm more interested in a way that I can remove that whitespace. That'd make responsive design easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31797927/remove-a-white-space-between-spans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the vertical alignment, the line-height and letter spacing to control the space:

```css
.title span {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT Pro Condensed', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Gill Sans';
}

.title .big {
  font-size: 250px;
  line-height:0.9em;
  letter-spacing:-0.2em;
}

.title .small {
  font-size: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="title flex">
  <span class="big">1</span>
  <span class="small">st</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you can use position relative, and move the second span closer to the first one. Something like:

```
.title .small {
  font-size: 60px;
  position:relative;
  left:-40px;
}
```

Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/vmn3bz0k/1/

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of potential answers to this question :)  My normal path would be to set the display of the first span to `display: inline-block` so you can set the width of the that span.

You can also play with negative margins on either span if you'd like to control it that way.

Or @hetious has a good solution too!

I'm sure there are several other ways you can approach this.  Happy coding!

```css
.title span {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans MT Pro Condensed', 'Gill Sans MT', 'Gill Sans';
}
.title .big {
    font-size: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75px;
}

.title .small {
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title flex">
  <span class="big">1</span>
  <span class="small">st</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, there are many possibilities to get this effect :)

Comment: One of the reasons I love code :D I do really like your solution. I just blasted out the first thing that popped in my mind.

Comment: So there's no way to remove the white space? I'm more interested in that, that'd make it easier for when it needs to be resized for a responsive design.

Comment: Kind of a yes and no answer -- the problem is the font-family that you're using.  The white space you're running into is a product of values set by the font.  If you don't want to mess with display or position you can use `letter-spacing: -180px` or whatever value you find appropriate.  That takes the problem straight to the font, but I would test it a bit ensure expected display.

Comment: You can also check out the CSS for `font-kerning` but it doesn't have IE/Edge support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning