# how to implement a csv binding in an ng template?

Tags: angular

I have a scenario where an article object is being returned to my ViewModel like this:

```
article: { authors: [{id: 11, name: 'Bob Smith'}, {id: 22, name: 'John Jones'}]; }
```

I have a requirement where I need to write out the display like this: "Written by Bob Smith, John Jones"

The author names above should be urls which reload the page display based on the associated author id when clicked. How can I prevent the last comma from displaying in the csv?  The *ngIf logic in the template code below doesn't seem to be working:

```
<div>
    <span>Written by </span>
    <span *ngFor="let author of article.Authors; let last=last">
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" (click)="reloadByAuthorId(1134)">
            {{author.Name}} 
        </a>
        <span *ngIf="!last">,</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I figured out how to implement the csv last comma logic.  I updated my original code example above with the following declaration:

```
let last=last
```

However, the template is rendering with a space before the comma.  Any idea how I can update the template to remove this extra space?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Are you still looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably adjust via CSS( the paddings, margins and font size... https://stackoverflow.com/a/25667514),
but also like this:

```
  <span  *ngIf="!last">{{author.name}},</span>
  <span  *ngIf="last">{{author.name}}</span>
```

**[**DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p9ywnp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)****