# Open and close tag difference

Tags: html

Hy guys, is there a difference between `<li>Hello wolrd</li>` and `<li>Hello world`.

Both tags have the same result:

> - Hello world

I know that every tag should have an close tag but I discovered this by mistake. Can anyone tell me the reason?

Comment: First is correct syntax. Second is not. Browsers can/try to work around missing closing tag, but you will sometimes have to guess where this closing tag will be placed by browser.

Comment: Yes, one is closed, one is not. One is valid HTML, and one is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML: Include, or exclude, optional closing tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags)

Comment: @mishik — Both are correct. End tags for list items are optional.

Comment: @sevenseacat — You don't need an explicit end tag to close a list item element. Both are valid HTML.

Comment: @Quentin: Both are valid - but still it is better to pay attention to write closed tags with their closing parts. :)

Comment: @Václav — That's highly subjective.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Quentin yeah well the second one shouldn't be. *grumbles*

Answer (score 5):

In HTML some closing tags are optional. `</li>` is one of them.

From [the HTML5 syntax W3C recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags):

> An li element's end tag may be omitted if the li element is
>   immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more
>   content in the parent element.

Comment: It isn't just HTML 5. That's been true of all versions of HTML. Some start tags are optional too.

Answer (score 2):

No, actually there isn't, if you follow the rules described in the spec.

The HTML specification, both [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) provide a way to write `<li>` without closing tag, since it can be logically derived from the markup.

The rule is, as pointed out in the HTML spec:

> An `li` element's end tag may be omitted if the `li` element is immediately followed by another `li` element or if there is no more content in the parent element.

Comment: How is it not valid HTML4? Optional closing tags have been optional forever...? http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html This isn't about screwing up. This is about HTML not being XML... (of course, you may argue that the specs were screwed up)

Comment: "Now, even the HTML standard tries to compensate" — End tags for li elements have been optional since they were introduced in [the original HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt).

Comment: I updated the answer thanks to your comments. Thanks Lukas and Quentin. (and indeed, I always loved XHTML...)

Comment: @AlexandruCostinel: As pointed out correctly by the two guys above, it is a little different than described in my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

HTML will in some cases be allowed to have errors and still run successfully (as someone else mentioned in this case it may be omitted). This doesn't mean you should be doing that. There's also the doctype declaration which you could leave out, you can put  tags outside of the body, but it's not the correct way to do it.

Having these kind of mistakes may seem to work now, but it may also cause problems (and that might differ per browser). It will also impact your page rank on google. 
Use the https://validator.w3.org/ to ensure you have as few problems on the page as possible.

Comment: "HTML will in some cases allow errors" — No it won't. Browsers might, but HTML doesn't. This, however, is not an error.

Comment: I mentioned that in this case it may be omitted.

Comment: Your answer consists of two paragraphs of irrelevant discussion of errors with just half a sentence of parenthesised content that actually addresses the question… by paraphrasing "someone else".