# CSS tags in scriptlets

Tags: javascript, html, css, scriptlet

I need to set an ID because I want to separate code form style. This is the code:

```
        <table class="form">
            <tr>
                <td class="InitialPadding">
                    <% if (message.equals("DATABASE ALREADY EXIST")){
                        out.print("<font color='red'>"+message);
                    }
                    else{
                        out.print("<font color='green'>"+message);
                    }

                    %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The CSS that contanins the color is inside a css file, here is the hierarchy:

```
--Web Pages
     -css
         global.css //THIS IS THE CSS FILE
     -images
         background.jpg

     -index.html
     -install.html  //THIS IS WHERE THE SCRIPTLET IS
--Source Packages
--etc
```

How I can set an use an ID inside the out print, something like this:

```
  out.print("<id="error">"+message);
```

instead of:

```
out.print("<font color='red'>"+message);
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about `out.print("<span class='error'>"+message+"</span>");`and a css style `span.error { color: red; }`

Comment: out of curiosity, what is the reason for the `<font>` tags and `<table class='form'>`? this is unusual mark-up for 2015

Comment: I asumed that font color='red' is the sintax for print red color message. The table class='form' is a css style that takes all table and forms it with a custom style. It is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give the element a type.
2. Don't use double quotes in a variable delimited by double quotes

Such:

```
out.print("<p id='error'>" + message);
```

Comment: Do you not need a closing tag `</p>` too?

Comment: @HasseBjörk — No. It's optional and has been since the original HTML spec.

Comment: Thank you! It seems I have been doing too much XHTML-programming. It is not necessary in [HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags)