# Html paragraph why still print out the result?

Tags: html

### Paragraph

why `<p> hello </a>` still print out the result?
i know that the proper one is this `<p> hello </p>`

anyone willing to explain this for me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML: Include, or exclude, optional closing tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags)

Comment: It will print all content in the `<p>` will consider all content is inside the para.

Comment: Like in complete <a>tag will convert all content into link

Comment: The HTML language is not very strict and the browsers are forgiving. As a general rule, if the tags are correctly written (any `<` has a corresponding `>`) anything you put outside of tags is visible in the browser (if not told otherwise by CSS).

Answer (score 1):

Unlike most other mark-up languages like XML or JSON, HTML was designed from the beginning to allow invalid code. Browsers are supposed to do their best and fix your errors. Whether you have static HTML or you use a server-side language like PHP to generate it is completely irrelevant: the browser doesn't know or care about how you've created the mark-up.

You can see browser's fixes with built-in developer tools (in most browsers it's mapped to <kbd>F12</kbd> or you can right click and select *Inspect Element*):

[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

The opening p tag is enough for it to work, but you need the closing tag in order to make sure that elements that come after function correctly. Without the proper closing tag your code will inevitably face issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic HTML, not much to do with PHP; For all you care you can even create a blank file called "index.html" or "index.php" and type in it `hello` without any brackets, any headers etc. and you will still get the web browser to display "hello".

Now for paragraphs - you can easily type `<p>hello` without a closing

and this will work fine for MOST browsers, but it is inadvisable to do so, because it might produce unexpected results.

You should read a bit more about HTML's paragraphs, for example here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_paragraphs.asp