# Skipping html closing tags

Tags: html, minify

Google chrome (and probably all the recent browsers) automatically adds the closing tag of html elements when they are missing.
**It will automatically add the closing tag at the end of the element parent**.

**Example 1:**

```
<tag1>content1<tag2>content2<tag3>content3
```

**Will output:**

```
<tag1> 
    content1 
    <tag2> 
        content2
        <tag3> 
            content3 
        </tag3>
    </tag2> 
</tag1>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<tag1>content1<tag2>content2</tag2><tag3>content3
```

**Will output:**

```
<tag1> 
    content1 
    <tag2> 
        content2
    </tag2>
    <tag3> 
        content3 
    </tag3>
</tag1>
```

I know that the previous html examples are **invalid and difficult to read**. But removing closing html tags following this rule with an **html minifier** could reduce the templates's size. Why aren't html minifier using this rule ? Is there some restrictions ?

**Edit:** *Context: I am not talking about any name tag in particular, that's why i used `tagX` in my examples. Eg. with angularjs element directives*

Comment: They are invalid because you are using made up elements instead of HTML. Some elements have optional end tags (and some have optional start tags) and can be perfectly valid.

Comment: We can't tell you why an HTML minifier isn't taking advantage of optional tag rules because you haven't told us which piece of software you are talking about (and the answer would probably be either "because you didn't set the right options" or "how should we know, ask the author" anyway)

Comment: Why do you even care about saving a couple dozen bytes? Add some new icon to your navigation and any savings are wiped out.

Comment: Because minification is definitely not a primary goal. Absolutely unreadable and not maintainable code, which is only understood by you, for a week after coding is not worth 1 KB of data in 2016, when people have 100+ MBit Internet. People cld actlly skp almst all vwls and it wld hgly rdce th amnt of sent dt, but we do not. It's simply not worth it.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev — "minification is definitely not a primary goal". It should be. The OP called the tool his was talking about "an html minifier"

Comment: FWIW, I used to run my homepage through a minifier script which **did** remove optional end tags. It cut about 10% off the size of the HTML before gzipping IIRC.

Comment: I am no talking about any tool and i know there is some optional closing tags (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags) but i am talking about dynamic tags like the ones provided in my examples. My question is relevant when you use angular templates with custom directives (custom tag names). What tool were you talking about quentin ? Does it support custom tag names ?

Comment: @AntoineEsteve — You said "Why aren't html minifier using this rule ?". The HTML minifier that you are talking about is a tool.

Comment: @AntoineEsteve — "i am talking about dynamic tags like the ones provided in my examples" — What is a "dynamic tag"? Do you mean a completely made up one that isn't allowed in an HTML document? So you're asking why, when people write *completely invalid HTML*, they don't omit end tags?

Comment: "My question is relevant when you use angular templates with custom directives (custom tag names)" — You were asking about HTML. Why are you bringing Angular templates in to it *now*? Did you mean angular templates all along? Maybe you should rewrite the question to explain that in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good observation. This has been done by Firefox for a long time as well as it helps developers with semantics. But the issue we run into is what we just mentioned. Firefox, Chrome. But what does IE do? Or screenreaders? I know Safari is not doing this at the same level FF and Chrome are.

It comes down to browser support and having a general global consensus on valid html. Having a blueprint to work with instead of browser specific implementations means we can run web technology more safely across old and new devices who are not fail safe-ing their parsers.

Comment: Browsers have been relatively consistent about they handle invalid HTML for a long time. HTML 5 includes parsing rules designed to make them *more* consistent. Plenty of elements have explicitly optional end tags, so it might not even be invalid HTML that the question is asking about (unfortunately the examples given are not [MCVE]s)

Comment: As far screenreaders, I'm not aware of any that deal with the raw HTML. Only the APIs supplied to them by browsers.

Comment: @Quentin This is what I mean. "relatively consistent" and not knowing the capabilities of devices hitting the market is already a good thing to stick to overal standards. Screen readers in general rely on valid html to work. Depending on how advanced the device browser is this may or may not include fail-safe-ing html, closing tags for you, or fixing your block or inline elements, which Firefox has been doing a lot, but safari not. Relying on specific browser implementations that may or "relatively consistent" is not supporting 100%.