# What determines if an element needs a closing tag?

Tags: html, dom

I was wondering what determines if an element needs a closing tag or not. For example, `input`, `br` and `hr` don't support being closed with `</element>` but their structure is simply `<element/>` (although I prefer just `<element>`) - with attributes if needed.

Also, how would I replicate this behaviour in a custom element?

Comment: the standards/recommendations define that.

Comment: depends if the element can have child nodes, or if the end tag can be inferred https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008593/html-include-or-exclude-optional-closing-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was wondering what determines if an element needs a closing tag or not.

Their definition in the HTML specification.

> but their structure is simply `<element/>`

The `/` is optional in HTML 5. It is only there for people who got used to the syntax when XHTML looked like the way forward.

> Also, how would I replicate this behaviour in a custom element?

You can't. The custom element specification doesn't provide any means to make an end tag optional or forbidden.